# Shell command to compile C in Gprbuild

Tags: c, ada, gprbuild

Using GtkAda, I'm trying to use the resource API to include the Glade file directly inside my code.

For this, we can generate C code from a set of resources using [*glib-compile-resources*](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/glib-compile-resources.html) which can then be linked to the Ada code.

The problem is that this C code requires Gtk includes which we usually get from the *pkg-config* command under Linux such as

```bsh
gcc -c -x c `pkg-config --cflags gio-2.0` myglade.gresource.c
```

I'd like to know how to provide the same kind of information in a *GPRBuild* project file.

FYI, I already tried to use the *pkg-config* command inside the compiler package for C language without any success. Of course, I managed to build by hand but that's a bit long :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
project Config_Demo is
   Pkg_Config := external_as_list ("PKG_CONFIG", " ");
   package Compiler is
      --  only this file needs the extra switches
      for Switches ("myglade.gresource.c") use Pkg_Config;
   end Compiler;
end Config_Demo;
```

and then

```
gprbuild -P config_demo -XPKG_CONFIG="`pkg-config -cflags gio-2.0`"
```

Comment: I wondered whether you could provide a special addition to the GPR configuration database which would use the `<external>` feature, which runs an external command; but it’s only legal in a `<compiler_description>` element, and introducing a new "compiler" for this seems ... wrong. Also, not sure how to get the result as a list - it’s intended for querying the compiler, e.g. `-dumpmachine`.

Comment: Your first solution is working !... And I agree with you, providing a special compiler description in the GPR configuration database for this seems to me quite wrong as it's not the main purpose of it.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet will be to do what GtkAda does: Look at its [`shared.gpr.in`](https://github.com/AdaCore/gtkada/blob/master/shared.gpr.in) file, it uses the token `@GTK_LIBS_GPR@` which will be replaced by the configure script, giving a usable `shared.gpr`.

Thing is, you need to issue the pkg-config call and build your gpr file from the result *somehow*. GPRBuild is not equipped to do this for you and process the result. If you're comfortable with GNU autotools, you can look further at how GtkAda achieves it:

`GTK_LIBS_GPR` is set in [aclocal.m4](https://github.com/AdaCore/gtkada/blob/master/aclocal.m4#L330) using a macro that converts the C-style flags to a GPR array. The value comes from `GTK_LIBS` which is queried [here](https://github.com/AdaCore/gtkada/blob/master/aclocal.m4#L282) via pkg-config.

If you're not comfortable with GNU autotools, you can write your configure script using basic shell commandos, a scripting language like Python or with whatever other tool you're comfortable with.

Comment: I hoped there would be another way :)